# Flutter Visibility Toggle not working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, visibility

Creating a Screen where I want to perform Flutter-FireBase Searching.But Visibility Toggle is not working as desired.
**Desired Toggle Behaviour :** When clicked on TextForm field , prefix icon and result card should be visible. Upon Clicking the Prefix Icon(Back Arrow) , Result List (Card) and the prefix icon itself should become invisible and TextField should unfocus .
**Actual Behaviour :** On clicking the prefix icon , Result set and prefix icon **don't** disappear , Prefix icon remains there and result set becomes invisible but occupies some space beneath the TextFormField

```
class AddAppointmentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddAppointmentWidgetState createState() => _AddAppointmentWidgetState();
}

class _AddAppointmentWidgetState extends State<AddAppointmentWidget> {
  bool searchbartapped = false;
  var queryResultSet = [];
  var tempSearchStore = [];

// Search Function
  initiateSearch(value) {
    //body
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
          child: Text('Search',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff2a2a2a), fontSize: 18),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      initiateSearch(value);
                    },
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        searchbartapped = true;
                      });
                    },
                    cursorColor: Color(0xff2a2a2a),
                    cursorWidth: 1.5,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search by Name",
                        prefixIcon: Visibility(
                          visible: searchbartapped,
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  searchbartapped = !searchbartapped;
                                  queryResultSet = [];
                                  tempSearchStore = [];
                                });
                                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                              }),
                        ),
                        )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: searchbartapped,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                primary: false,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: tempSearchStore.map((element) {
                  print(element['name']);
                  return buildResult(context, element);
                }).toList()),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Note**  The buildResult widget is working perfectly fine.
**Problem is only with the visibilty toggle**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue:** When you tap the `prefixIcon`:

1. `onPressed` is called, setting `searchbartapped` to `false` which is what you want.
2. The `onTap` method of your `TextFormField` is also called (since `prefixIcon` is inside it), setting `searchbartapped` to `true`.

So what you want is to prevent the second event from happening. I tried to prevent the notification from bubbling up the tree but I couldn't. So what I ended up doing is a bit more manual but works just as well.

**Solution:** Add a variable (for example `hideSearchTapped`) which is set to true when the `prefixIcon` is called. Then when the `onTap` method of your `TextFormField` is called, check this variable:

- If `hideSearchTapped` is true, set it to false
- Else change `searchbartapped` as you did

Here is a working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: new AddAppointmentWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class AddAppointmentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddAppointmentWidgetState createState() => _AddAppointmentWidgetState();
}

class _AddAppointmentWidgetState extends State<AddAppointmentWidget> {
  bool searchbartapped = false;
  bool hideSearchTapped = false;
  var queryResultSet = [];
  var tempSearchStore = [];

// Search Function
  initiateSearch(value) {
    //body
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
          child: Text('Search', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff2a2a2a), fontSize: 18),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      initiateSearch(value);
                    },
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (hideSearchTapped) {
                          hideSearchTapped = false;
                        } else {
                          searchbartapped = true;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    cursorColor: Color(0xff2a2a2a),
                    cursorWidth: 1.5,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Search by Name",
                      prefixIcon: Visibility(
                        visible: searchbartapped,
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            onPressed: () {
                              hideSearchTapped = true;
                              searchbartapped = !searchbartapped;
                              queryResultSet = [];
                              tempSearchStore = [];
                              setState(() {
                              });
                              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                              return true;
                            }),
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: searchbartapped,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                primary: false,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: tempSearchStore.map((element) {
                  print(element['name']);
                }).toList()),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** you should [use lowerCamelCase to name your variable](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#identifiers). So `searchbartapped` would become `searchBarTapped`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)